# install laravel9.1 by sail docker-compose cant build

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

After using sail build --no-cache command, apt-key is stuck。

```
mysql uses an image, skipping
redis uses an image, skipping
meilisearch uses an image, skipping
mailhog uses an image, skipping
selenium uses an image, skipping
Building laravel.test
[+] Building 3654.7s (7/15)                                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.39kB                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:21.10                                                                                                                                                   0.7s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:21.10@sha256:cc8f713078bfddfe9ace41e29eb73298f52b2c958ccacd1b376b9378e20906ef                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 99B                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [ 3/11] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg    3653.7s
 => => # Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...                                                                                                                                                                   
 => => # 0 added, 0 removed; done.                                                                                                                                                                                    
 => => # Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...                                                                                                                                                            
 => => # done.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 => => # Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).                                                                                                              
 => => # Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.itanfA6ojm/gpg.1.sh --homedir /root/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C
```

please help me,how to solve this problem. thank you very much.